# Make Vuetify rule for number between 0 and 999 or no input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuetify.js

I have rule that checks if number in input is between 0 and 999, it works OK. Issue is that if I enter incorrect value like `a` and delete it then I still have error shown even for empty input.

It must have some simple solution, I just can't find it now.

I have left only important parts of the code.

```
<v-text-field 
type="number"
:rules="numberRule"/>

// Vue component
data: () => ({
numberRule: [v => (!isNaN(parseFloat(v)) && v >= 0 && v <= 999) || 'Number has to be between 0 and 999']
})
```

Comment: let me know if the below answer resolves your issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Above code looks fine, I've added fixes to your requirement

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/ZEEeVoW?editors=1010

The rules property in vuetify text-field expect an array of boolean values or string, if boolean is true then validation passed, if it finds any string then it displays as error message

> I've added fixes to the **numberRule** to first check if the value is
>   no input, the it wont display any error message, then  checks the
>   number from 0-999 if passes then no error message, if not passes both
>   the case, it displays error message

```
<v-text-field
 label="Regular"
 :rules="[numberRule]"
></v-text-field>
```

In Script:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    numberRule: v  => {
      if (!v.trim()) return true;
      if (!isNaN(parseFloat(v)) && v >= 0 && v <= 999) return true;
      return 'Number has to be between 0 and 999';
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works but

somehow it stops working for strings if I add `type="number"` to the `v-text-field`, this can be replicated in your codepen. I noticed that was also the reason why I couldn't catch any error with strings as I already had `type="number"` in my code.

Comment: Yes , if you set type="number" it allows only number as input, rules is not triggers for strings

Comment: Ah, it is weird I wanted to have combination of my desired rule with user being presented with numbers keyboard on mobile devices but it looks I will need to remove `type="number"` in order to make sure user entered numbers or just keep `type="number"` but do the type checking on submit.

Comment: You can disable submit button until and unless all the fields are valid without error

Comment: Oh, I just checked `type="number"` again, I thought it allows characters as input but it doesn't. Only thing that is allowed is `e`, probably for exponent numbers as for example 2e3 == 2000, other characters are not shown, so your rule will work!

There is no need for workaround, thanks for help!